# Persistent HTTP connections with httplib

Tags: python, http, httplib

I'm trying to write an application where I send an initial HTTP post message to server and leave the connection open.  The application then sits around until the server sends data back.  Once the server sends data back I want to read it and write it to a file (easy enough).

The part I'm having trouble with is actua

Basically I do this:

```
h=http.HTTPConnection(sever, port, timeout)
h.putrequest('POST', selector)
h.putheaders(...)
h.endheaders()
h.send(body)
buffering = False
while 1:
  r = h.getresponse(buffering)
  f=open(unique_filename, 'w')
  f.write(r.read())
  f.close()
```

What I expect is that the app should block in the loop and when data arrives it gets written to the file.  I suspect I'm using `read` the wrong way, but looking at the httplib source didn't help.

Also, the python documentation site mentions a `httplib.fileno()` that returns the socket httplib uses.  I'm using 2.7.0 and website doc is for 2.7.2, I can't find the `fileno()` method.  I suspect taking the socket over httplib and calling `recv` myself is the best way to go, is that a good idea?

Any help is appreciated with one exception: please don't tell me to use some other library.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a different library? `shutil.copyfileobj` + `urllib2.urlopen` seem to solve your exact problem in far fewer lines of code.

Comment: because this is part of a larger application that I've already built.